# So i wanna make the circle and the cow in the glass but i dont know how to form the lines to extrude it. can someone help me plx

Tags: modeling

[image]

So how do i make an oval in te glass and draw the cow to extrude it. 
I am very new to blender. Would be great if somebody could help me.
Thks alot

[image]

So this is the result. I think it looks pretty good. Only my cow looks a bit weird, so this i still have to figure out.

Comment: do you need it that way so that cow will be topology? Or it can be height texture map as well? Also it can be hard to model. I would suggest to subdivide your mesh a lot of times, use sculpting window, mask parts that are supposed to be extruded outwards and then pull it out. It could be easy but it will make a very dense topo, maybe you can bake it later into height texture

Comment: maybe look into the Knife Project tool, project the shape on your glass and extrude

Comment: ok thks guys i will try both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show you how to do the circle - you can do the same with the cow.

So here is one way:

1. add a cone (you already have that)

[image]

[image]

2. right click -> shade smooth

turn autosmooth on:

[image]

[image]

3. add mesh -> circle
4. move it with G -> X like so:

[image]

5. R -> Y -> 90

[image]

6. add shrinkwrap modifier: (adapt offset as you need it)

[image]

choose cone as target

[image]

7. add skin modifier

[image]

[image]

8. press TAB -> CTRL-A -> scale down

[image]

9. add subdivision surface modifier

[image]

[image]

S -> Y and scale to your needs

maybe S -> Z and scale too

[image]

Comment: wow great man thks !

Comment: If my answer helps you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't an ideal method, you'd be better of making a bump map of the cow and circle and using that instead